# Django Shell with autocomplete and colored text

Tags: python, django

About 6 months ago, I was developing with Django and could do the usual python manage.py shell. The command line would come up with colored text (classes were purple or something, functions were yellow, etc.) and allow me to type in a few characters, press tab, and it would suggest completions.  It was a huge help for learners like me, I think.

Now, it no longer does this. It's a boring black/gray terminal and tab completion doesn't work.

I'm using a Python 3.9 virtual environment, Django 3.2, and Pycharm (April 21).

Does the terminal show colored text and do completions for anyone else currently?  If so, please share your django/python versions & setup.  I would gladly replicate to get this functionality back.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think previously you were using the interactive terminal.

```
pip install ipython
```

Use this and the previous terminal will be back.

Comment: Worked instantaneously. Thanks! I think the cause was that I switched from my main python to a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the Django shell using shell_plus from django-extensions. It allows you to override the default prompt with ptpython (which offers autocomplete and custom color schemes).

- https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shell_plus.html
- https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/ptpython

Or see the examples in this post: https://django.wtf/blog/django-shell-colors-by-development-environment/